# ng-repeat without duplicates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any "angular way" to avoid displaying duplicates in `ng-repeat`?

If we add duplicates in the array it will pop-up `[ngRepeat:dupes]` and this can be solved with `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`. Good.

However what if we do not want to display the duplicates? I have thought to filter when creating the array like that:

```
if(!$scope.items.indexOf($scope.item ) == -1 ) {
    $scope.items.push( $scope.item );
}
```

But is there any other angular-ish way?

Answer (score 0):

One angular-ish way could be to create a filter that implements the unique filtering.

```
.filter('unique', function() {
    return function (lst) {
       var filteredLst = ...
       ... filtering logic here ...
       return filteredList;
    }
})
```

and then use it like:

```
 ng-repeat="item in items | unique"
```